# Why does my script log to the console fast then clears?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to log a message to the console when clicking a element.
It shows the message for a split second then it clears the console.
Why is it doing that?
I realized I had to move the script down on the page because otherwise the variable would of been null.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Learning</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <a href="">
                <section id="headSlot">
                </section>
            </a>

            <a href="">
                <section id="neckSlot">
                </section>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="">
                <section id="headSlot">
                </section>
            </a>

            <a href="">
                <section id="neckSlot">
                </section>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var headSlot = document.getElementById("headSlot");
headSlot.addEventListener("click", printToConsole);


function printToConsole() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because of your anchor tags. They're causing your page to refresh. Change your anchor tags to the following to disable page refresh:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

Or you can stop event propagation (Read more here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-simplified-explanation-of-event-propagation-in-javascript-f9de7961a06e).

```
function printToConsole(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Omg.. How did I not see that.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Beat me to it, an alternative way would be to remove them or to remove their functions via JavaScript

Comment: I noticed that it only registers on 1 of the elements, I guess that's because it only gets the first element with that ID? Is it possible to make it register on all elements with that ID

Comment: @MarkDenom - You'll want to change those to classes; not ID's. ID's should be unique where classes are not.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>`.